# Why does this print -0.0?

Tags: python, floating-point

Can anybody please explain why the following happens?

```
print(-1 * (605 % 11))        #-> 0
print(-1 * (0.5*1210 % 11))   #-> -0.0
print(-1 * (0.5*1210) % 11)   #-> 0.0
```

Especially the `-0.0` is baffling..

Comment: Why shouldn't it print -0.0? That's what you get when you multiply 0.0 by -1.

Comment: step through the order of operations, operator precedence, etc

Comment: because its a floating point value and not an integer?

Comment: This is a good question. In ordinary arithmetic you get 0.0 when you multiply 0.0 by -1. The IEEE floating point standard associates a sign with zero for computational reasons: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
print(-1 * (605 % 11))        #-> 0
```

Integer arithmetic. No surprises here.

```
print(-1 * (0.5*1210 % 11))   #-> -0.0
```

Here's where you might get surprised. `0.5*1210 % 11` evaluates to floating-point zero, and then `-1 * 0.0` results in *negative zero*, which is a thing in floating-point. It exists because it makes edge cases of some numeric algorithms easier to implement.

```
print(-1 * (0.5*1210) % 11)   #-> 0.0
```

Here's where someone more familiar with floating-point than with Python might get surprised. `-1 * (0.5*1210)` evaluates to `-605.0`, but then in `-605.0 % 11`, Python defines the `%` operation as returning a result of the same sign as the denominator, rather than the numerator, so this returns `0.0` instead of `-0.0`.